# Add element to different columns in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This code takes in an object and i'm trying to make a jtable with three columns that displays the id,firstname and lastname of the object. Right now the id is going across the row rather than down the column. How do i change it?

```
public class Main {
  private RealPayroll obj;

public Main(RealPayroll obj1){
   obj=obj1;
}

public void run() {
obj.runPayroll(4);
Vector rowData = new Vector();
String id[]=new String[50];
String firstname[]=new String[50];
String lastname[]=new String[50];


for (int i=0;i<obj.getPaySlips().length;i++)
{
    id[i]=String.valueOf(obj.getPaySlips()[i].getId());
    firstname[i]=obj.getPaySlips()[i].getFirstName();
    lastname[i]=obj.getPaySlips()[i].getLastName();   
}

Vector rowOne=new Vector();
for (int i= 0; i < obj.getPaySlips().length; i++) {
  Vector colData = new Vector(Arrays.asList(id[i]));
  rowOne.add(colData);
}

Vector rowTwo=new Vector();
 for (int i = 0; i < obj.getPaySlips().length; i++) {
     Vector col2Data = new Vector(Arrays.asList(firstname[i]));
     rowTwo.add(col2Data);
}

String[] columnNames = {"Id","FirstName","LastName"};
rowData.addElement(rowOne);
rowData.addElement(rowTwo);
Vector columnNamesV = new Vector(Arrays.asList(columnNames));

JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNamesV);
table.setBounds(5,89,280,471);
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(300, 300);
f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
f.setVisible(true);
```

}
  }

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic should be something like this:

1. Create an empty DefaultTableModel.
2. Add individual rows of data to the table model.
3. Create the table:

Pseudo code:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Id","FirstName","LastName"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

for (all the items in the payroll)
{
    Vector row = new Vector();
    row.addElement( payroll id );
    row.addElement( payroll firstName);
    row.addElement( payroll lastName);
    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```